# git submodules - how to undo git submodule update --init

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git project with several submodules within.
Between now and a year ago several submodules have moved - even some of the same have been moved a directory level down.  Another one moved from one URL to another and location location. Git does not take such changes kindly :)

When I have my git and have run `git submodule update --init` - then I cannot run

```
$ git checkout OLDSHA
fatal: not a git repository: sub/depdir/../../.git/modules/sub/depdir
```

or I get

```
fatal: could not get a repository handle for submodule 'sub/depdir'
```

If I clone the git from scratch, run `git checkout OLDSHA` - AND THEN `git submodule update --init`, no problems.

**Then my question:**

- Is there a way to undo `git submodule update --init` which essentially brings me back to what I get after `git clone PROJECT && cd project && git checkout OLDSHA`

Note; this is NOT about getting rid of my submodules. The problem is to enable my e.g. to run git bisect across these changes more effetively without having to re-clone from scratch.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a truly clean way to deal with this. The absorbed Git directories provide a possible solution but don't actually solve the real problem (which is: remapping the submodules' locations without re-cloning the submodule repositories).

Comment: @torek thanx for your input. What do you mean by "The absorbed Git directories"?

Comment: For a fairly long time now (I think it was even backported to Git 1.7.x but it's standard in 2.x), `git submodule absorbgitdirs` moves the `.git` repository directory of each submodule into a subdirectory of the `.git` directory of the highest-level superproject repository, and `git submodule update --init` clones any new submodules with their repositories redirected like this. In the bad old days each submodule repository was kept in the top level of the work-tree of each submodule repository.

Comment: For instance, suppose you have a superproject that you clone with `git clone <url> sp`. This gives you a checked out copy of the superproject Git in `./sp`; the actual *repository* for this is `./sp/.git`. Suppose further that `sp` contains a submodule named `path/to/sub`. Then there is a `./sp/path/to/sub/`. In `sp/path/to/sub`, in the old (pre-absorb) days, there would exist `sp/path/to/sub/.git/` holding the submodule *repository* along with `sp/path/to/sub/*` holding the checked-out files *from* the submodule.

Comment: In the modern setup, `sp/path/to/sub/.git` is a *file* containing the path to the submodule repository itself, which is now in `sp/.git/modules/<more-path>`. So in the modern setup, `rm -rf sp/path/to/sub` *does not destroy* the submodule *repository*, just the checkout. In the older setup, it actually destroys the entire submodule *repository*.

Comment: Good comments @torek

Answer (score 2):

With the newer git I can now run

```
git submodule deinit sub/depdir
```

and then

```
git checkout some_old_sha
```

works like a charm